how do force the programmer to instantiate a template?
Here is some template constexpr function.
template <class> constexpr void function();

I want to force the programmer to instantiate function with a specific template parameter.
template void function<int>(); // the program is well-formed

If the programmer didn't do this, I want a compile-time error.
How to achieve this?

This looks like an XY problem. Why do you want to do this?

If the instantiation of a template causes a difference in behaviour somewhere else, your design is incorrect.

I definitely got into an XY problem. need to ask differently

what would the error be good for? what would happen is someone does not instantiate it?

The simplest example is using static_assert, so that invalid templates cannot be instantiated (thus compiled):
#include <type_traits>

template <class T> constexpr void function() {
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, int>);
    // ... function implementation
}

int main() {
    function<int>();
    //function<unsigned int>();
    //function<float>();
}


I understood the question as requiring function<int>, not as forbidding anything else.
